# PostgreSQL DbLink Compilation on Solaris 10

Tags: postgresql, dblink

After successfully building dblink on solaris 10 using Sun C 5.9
SunOS_sparc 2007/05/03 and gmake.

I ran gmake installcheck and got the following output:

```
========== running regression test queries        ==========

test dblink               ... FAILED

======================

 1 of 1 tests failed.
```

The differences that caused some tests to fail can be viewed in the
file "./regression.diffs".  A copy of the test summary that you see
above is saved in the file "./regression.out".

First error in regression.diffs file:

> psql:dblink.sql:11: ERROR:  could not load library "/apps/postgresql/
>   lib/dblink.so": ld.so.1: postgre
>   s: fatal: relocation error: file /apps/postgresql/lib/dblink.so:
>   symbol PG_GETARG_TEXT_PP: referenced symbol not found

I am running postgreSQL version 8.2.4 with the latest dblink source.

Has anyone got any idea what I need to do to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue I tried using the 8.2 dblink sources, instead of the latest version.

You also need to make sure you use gnu make not the sun make.

Comment: Ok, but which of the issues (file not there at all, file in wrong place, permissions) really caused the server to not find it?

Answer (score 0):

Does the file it is looking for actually exist?   Is it in that location?

It may be one of a few things I can think of:
1)  The thing did not compile, and therefore does not exist.
2)  It exists, but somewhere else, and the environment variable that tells it where to find it is set wrong.
3)  The permissions are such that the ID that the postmaster is running as cannot traverse to that directory.

To check if it is somewhere else:

```
find / -type f|grep dblink.so
```

To check the permissions:

```
su - 
su - postgres
less /apps/postgresql/ lib/dblink.so
```